# How do I use Jquery variable variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a lot of questions about if it is possible to use variable variables in jQuery.

One of the questions is this one: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript).

I tried to use the answer, but I don't know how I can use it in my case.

```
var numberofquestions = 10;   
var dataString = "";
for ( var i=1; i<=numberofquestions; i++ ) {
        /* ------ first  part ------- */
        if (i==1) {
            dataString = dataString + "q1=" + question1 + "&";
        } /* ------ end first part ------- */
        else if (i == numberofquestions) {
            questionValue = "question" + numberofquestions;
            qValue = "q" + numberofquestions;
            dataString = dataString + qValue + "=" + questionValue;
            console.log(dataString);
        } else {
            questionValue = question + i;
            dataString = dataString + "q" + i + "=" + questionValue +  "&";

        }
    }
```

The loop will run 10 times, and each time it needs to add a part to the already existing dataString.

What it needs to do is make this string:

```
q1=(value of var question1)&q2=(value of var question2) and so forth.
```

The vars `question1, question2, ... question10` all hold a number.

The first part works, it outputs q1=5 in the console log, however, after comes a random string. The output string (the total string) looks like:

```
q1=5&q2=NaN&q3=NaN&q4=NaN&q5=NaN&q6=NaN&q7=NaN&q8=NaN&q9=NaN&q10=question10
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @meagar agreed. And where is `jQuery` in this code?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to with "variable of variables".  All you are doing is appending a variable value to the end of the another variable value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an array for this. There is no such thing as "variable variables" in JavaScript.

You can access a variable through a string containing the variables name by using `this[variableName]`, but again, you shouldn't. You should use an array for this.

In your case, you would use `questionValue = this["question" + i]`, but one more time: **Don't do it**. Use an array instead.

I'm not sure why you're using `"question" + numberofquestions` which will be `10` every time

Comment: Wait. i got confused... you're saying "you should use an array for this..." and then "don't use an array"... wait, what..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy There is a tiny period after the bold don't

Comment: @user3669154 oops... he blends in very well with the dust particles on screen :D